# Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined in a jQuery carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

I am getting an error that I don't understand. I thought that the error may be with the way I referenced the jQuery or how I used the click, but everything that I've tried there hasn't worked.

Here's my javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next-link").on("click", function() {
    var currentActiveImage = $("image-shown");
    var nextActiveImage = currentActiveImage.next();
    //var i = 

    if (nextActiveImage.length == 0) {
      nextActiveImage = $(".carousel-inner img").first();
    }

    currentActiveImage.removeClass("image-shown").addClass("image-hidden").css("z-index", -10);
    nextActiveImage.addClass("image-shown").removeClass("image-hidden").css("z-index", 20);
    $(".carousel-inner img").not([currentActiveImage, nextActiveImage]).css("z-index", 1);

    i.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

I insert it into my html file with:

```html
<script src="./js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="./js/test.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is `i` defined? What are you expecting it to be? Assuming you want it to be the event which was triggered, then you need to accept it as an argument to your handler function: http://api.jquery.com/click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`i` should be referenced in click function event.

```
$(".next-link").on("click", function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the way it is used, it is clear that `i` is supposed to be an **event** object, but apparantly it is not. The way to get that object is through the **click** `function()` that now has no parameters.

Besides all that, your code will be a lot clearer if you actually call it `event` (instead of `i`).

That gives us the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next-link").on("click", function(event) { // Added "event" parameter

    // Your regular code    

    event.preventDefault(); // Signal that the event has been handled and that processing must stop
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.